# Como colocar 2 eventos .click() em um button

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou fazendo um painel de administrador, onde tem as seguintes opções de buttons

Dashboard `class="dashboard-button"`

Settings `class="settings-button"`

Contents `class="contents-button"`

Feedback `class="feedback-button"`

Todos eles tem o mesmo id `id="options"`

E ao clicar em akgum button, aparece um nav em baixo com as opções de links

E o meu jquery está assim

```
$(".dashboard-button").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-dashboard").addClass("active");
});
```

Obs a classe `navbar-dashboard` é a que vai aparecer ao clicar no button
Ja a classe `active` é a que tem o css `display bloxk` pois inicialmente a navbar tem display none

Resumindo o que eu quero é, ao clicar no button, a navbar aparece 
E se o usuario clicar novamente no mesmo button, ela some

Alguem poderia me iluminar? To a uma hora quebrando a cabeça pra achar uma solução kkkkk

Comment: pelo que entendi basta você substituir o método addClass("active") por toggleClass("active")

Comment: O atributo global `id` define um identificador para um elemento, deve ser único e exclusivo em todo o documento.[MDN WEBDocs `id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode verificar se existe a classe *active* com **hasClass**. Se ela existir, remova-a com **removeClass**. E se não existir, adicione-a com **addClass**.

```
$(".dashboard-button").click(function(){
    if ($(".navbar-dashboard").hasClass("active")) {
        $(".navbar-dashboard").removeClass("active");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-dashboard").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Fiz um exemplo funcionando:
https://jsfiddle.net/8m75jozh/1/

Answer (score 0):

Só exemplificando o que o **Gabriel José de Oliveira** disse ali nos comentários:

```
$(".dashboard-button").click(function(){
    $(".navbar-dashboard").toggleClass("active");
});
```

A função `toggleClass` adiciona a classe quando não existe e remove a classe quando ela existe.

Mais informações: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/